# Efficiently threading with a default value for missing parts / defining custom behavior for addition of expressions with a given head

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, customization

In short, I would like to be able to "add" expressions with a particular head (call it `h` for our purposes) which will always appear with a sequence of (non-negative) integer arguments as follows (for example):

```
h[a,b,c] + h[d,e]
```

> h[a+d,b+e,c]

```
h[]+h[a,b]
```

> h[a,b]

It seems that defining custom behavior for `Plus` is already a bit clunky and it's generally recommended just to define a separate function for this, so let's say for now that it's satisfactory to write a function `hPlus` that does this:

```
hPlus[h[a,b,c],h[d,e]]
```

> h[a+d,b+e,c],

and so on.

In general, the behavior is the same as that for sums of lists, with the caveat that whenever one expression is shorter than the other, it is treated as though it has an arbitrarily long tail of zeros.

I have already implemented this sort of "ragged addition" for lists (in practice, of integers) roughly as follows:

```
RaggedAdd[{list1, list2, ...}]:= ConstantArray[1,n].PadRight[{list1, list2, ...}]
```

Where `n` in the above is the number of lists being added. I'm also aware there is a similarly efficient solution to this particular problem using Transpose.

So of course one option for my "generalized" case is simply to use the solution for lists after replacing instances of `h` with `List`:

```
hPlus[x___h]:=h@@RaggedAdd[(List@@#)&/@{x}]
```

However, I find that the overhead of this superficial head-switching process degrades the performance relative to the equivalent operation for lists. Moreover, for cases where all the expressions `h[n1,n2,...]` occurring in `x___h` being added happen to have the same length, doing something like

```
Thread[Plus[x],h]
```

Is significantly faster than

```
h@@(Plus@@((List@@#)&/@{x})),
```

and the former actually achieves performance very close to that for straightforward addition of lists.

In my mind, I'm essentially trying to teach `Thread` to just supply a default value of 0 whenever it encounters a missing part in any of the arguments supplied to `Plus`, but it seems there is no built-in way to do this, which strikes me as an unfortunate oversight. Anyway, I'm looking for the method here which runs the fastest, however cryptic the code might look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this any better:  `ClearAll[h]; Plus[x__h] ^:= h @@ Plus @@ PadRight[List @@@ {x}];
h[a, b, c] + h[x, y]`?

Comment: The idea of using upvalues to customize behavior of addition is good, I hadn't come across that when I was looking around for answers before. I also neglected the more elegant use of @@@ as in your comment. It looks like this does improve the performance a bit, though the "equivalent" implementation working directly with lists is still about twice as fast, and in the case of adding lists of equal lengths it looks like the built-in behavior is about an order of magnitude faster than either the "ragged addition of h's" or just using Thread[Plus[x],h], which are actually close in performance(!)

Comment: To add to that -- I'm guessing this might be about as good as it gets without spending an inordinate amount of time trying to write some kind of compiled function or something overkill like that, so I might just have to eat the (minor? not totally clear how important this will be down the line) performance reduction.

Comment: Try: `h /: h[arg1__] + h[arg2__] := h @@ Plus @@ PadRight[{{arg1}, {arg2}}];`